# Kinect Infrared Camera Not working

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, infrared

I am using the Kinect 2 with the newest available SDK version 2.0. Everything works except IR, tested it with both SDK infrared demo example and Kinect Studio, both result in a black screen. I also looked at the code and capturing Kinect IR frames does not result in any errors, it just consists of all minimum values.

This is quite weird, as I thought IR was used to calculate depth and I can successfully read depth information. Also, I checked (with my cellphone camera) that the IR emitter is turned on and off correctly, just data is not received correctly for some reason.

After encountering the problem I made a fresh install on another computer, as I suspected I had broken my system somehow. I got exactly the same results after installing Kinect SDK. Everything except infrared works.

Has anyone seen this kind of behaviour before?

Comment: That's a shame. Good luck fixing it. Did you have a question?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post and added a question.

Comment: I have the same problem. Some works but Infrared doesnt work at all. Only black screen. Did you solved it?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I am simply working on computers that don't have this problem right now. Until now I haven't seen any good suggestions besides updating video card drivers and reinstalling Kinect SDK, some people claim it works (not for me, maybe I do it wrong somehow). Nevertheless, for two modern computers with fresh Windows installs, on one computer it works, on another it does not.

Answer (score 0):

check this out

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/70dcceb7-8d2f-485f-b3e9-f2d4b399fbe7/kinect-v2-infrared-not-working?forum=kinectv2sdk

try updating graphics card drivers

Comment: Unfortunately I have already tried all that. I have also tested it on many computers already (all are quite modern computers) and IR seems to work on only a half of them. I haven't found any pattern yet unfortunately.