# Kinect V2 IR Video Stream

Tags: kinect

I'm working on a new application which can access the video stream from the Kinect V2 sensor.  I've got the application working with the standard RGB and Depth video streams... but I am running into an issue with the IR video stream.  I've modified the example [found here](http://pterneas.com/2014/02/20/kinect-for-windows-version-2-color-depth-and-infrared-streams/) to fit my application... but the pixel values that I am returning as part of my bitmap are always black (ie. value = 0).  Here's the part of the code that I have running in my MultiSourceFrameArrived event handler:

```
    using (InfraredFrame IRFrame = framew.InfraredFrameReference.AcquireFrame())
    {
      if (IRFrame != null)
      {
        FrameDescription FrameDesc = IRFrame.FrameDescription;
        ushort[] IRData = new ushort[FrameDesc.Width * FrameDesc.Height];
        IRImgBuffer = new byte[4 * FrameDesc.Width * FrameDesc.Height];
        IRFrame.CopyFrameDataToArray(IRData);
        int colorIndex = 0;
        for (int IRIndex = 0; IRIndex < IRData.Length; ++IRIndex)
        {
          ushort depth = IRData[IRIndex];
          ushort ir = IRData[IRIndex];
          byte intensity = (byte)(ir >> 8);

          IRImgBuffer[colorIndex++] = (byte)ir; // Blue
          IRImgBuffer[colorIndex++] = (byte)ir; // Green
          IRImgBuffer[colorIndex++] = (byte)ir; // Red

          ++colorIndex;
        }
        gotframe = true;
      }
    }
```

It's even more frustrating as I can't seem to launch this in the debugger.  If I put a breakpoint in the code to see what the Blue pixel value (for example) is - the debugger never seems to catch it (not entirely sure why).  Can anyone help me understand why the intensity value is always 0?

Comment: What do you get for `IRData.Length`?  It seems as if you are never jumping into your `for` loop. So my first assumption is that `IRData.Length = 0`

Comment: IRData.Length is returning a value of 217088... which makes sense because the resolution of the IR resolution of the camera (according to this site: http://pterneas.com/2014/02/08/kinect-for-windows-version-2-overview/) is 512 x 424 = 217088... so I think it is getting into the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the issue was happening because of an outdated graphics card.  See this thread: [Kinect Infrared Camera Not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26934464/kinect-infrared-camera-not-working).  I have a relatively new laptop, but once I updated my Nvidia drivers it now seems to be working.